# Memory/Performance differences of declaring variable for return result of method call versus inline method call

Tags: java

Are there any performance or memory differences between the two snippets below? I tried to profile them using visualvm (is that even the right tool for the job?) but didn't notice a difference, probably due to the code not really doing anything.

Does the compiler optimize both snippets down to the same bytecode? Is one preferable over the other for style reasons?

```
boolean valid = loadConfig();
if (valid) {
    // OK
} else {
    // Problem
}
```

versus

```
if (loadConfig()) {
    // OK
} else {
    // Problem
}
```

Comment: You can easily check it with `javap`. In any case it doesn't matter, as that sort of micro-optimization has nothing to do with actual performance.

Comment: Thanks, I had never heard of  javap. I'll do some more research.

Comment: Thanks for the accept!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The real answer here: it doesn't even matter so much what javap will tell you how the corresponding bytecode looks like!

If that piece of code is executed like "once"; then the difference between those two options would be in the range of nanoseconds (if at all).

If that piece of code is executed like "zillions of times" (often enough to "matter"); then the JIT will kick in. And the JIT will optimize that bytecode into machine code; very much dependent on a lot of information gathered by the JIT at runtime.

Long story short: you are spending time on a detail so subtle that it doesn't matter in practical reality.

What matters in practical reality: the **quality** of your source code. In that sense: pick that option that "reads" the best; given your context.

Given the comment: I think in the end, this is (almost) a pure *style* question. Using the first way it might be easier to trace information (assuming the variable isn't boolean, but more complex). In that sense: there is no "inherently" better version. Of course: option 2 comes with one line less; uses one variable less; and typically: when one option is as readable as another; and one of the two is shorter ... then I would prefer the shorter version.

Comment: While this isn't wrong, the sheer number of these kind of answers do annoy me slightly: who are we to judge *why* OP wants to know this? Maybe he/she isn't optimizing at all. Maybe this question was born out of pure curiosity. I'd rather see a horribly technical abstract on how Java, its just-in-time-compilers and virtual machines and what-not work (with an added *side node* of "don't optimize prematurely etc etc". But maybe that's just me.

Comment: Not really; I hear your words; and I dont disagree. And I will for sure upvote a distinct answer to the question; and not mind if that answer gets accepted. But I have seen too many newbies here that assumed such things matter; and that is worth spending time to "optimize" around them.

Comment: I started thinking about this because I have a style preference (I like the second block I wrote) but I was wondering if one way or the other is *better* than the other.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to use the variable only once then the compiler/optimizer will resolve the explicit declaration.

Another thing is the code quality. There is a very similar rule in sonarqube that describes this case too:

> Local Variables should not be declared and then immediately returned or thrown
>
> Declaring a variable only to immediately return or throw it is a bad practice.
>   Some developers argue that the practice improves code readability, because it enables them to explicitly name what is being returned. However, this variable is an internal implementation detail that is not exposed to the callers of the method. The method name should be sufficient for callers to know exactly what will be returned.

https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/RSPEC-1488

Comment: That's a nice quote that fits the second part of the question very well.

Comment: Thank you for the link, I agree with the style comments. I prefer the second block over the first. I was asking more out of curiosity if one way or the other is better for performance (even if it is negligible). Thanks!